sqlModel type annotation when default Value is None in column
from sqlmodel import Field, SQLModel

class Hero(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = None

In the above the type annotation for id is int  but in the Field its mentioned that this column can have a default value of None
Then as per that it should be
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)

or

    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)


In the docs the model annotation includes the default (https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/automatic-id-none-refresh/#__tabbed_1_1)
